# In Blackberry How to customize font colors and still use a RichList

Tags: blackberry, fonts

How can we change a font color while using Rich List in Blackberry.

Comment: Did you try changing color of the manager (`Manager object that will hold the contents of a RichList`)? Override paint method of the manager and do something like this, `paint(graphics){graphics.setColor(myColor);super.paint(graphics);}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
final VerticalFieldManager vfm = new VerticalFieldManager(){
        protected void paint(Graphics graphics){
            graphics.setColor(0x36c9e3);
            super.paint(graphics);
            }
    };
 RichList list = new RichList(vfm, true,1, 2);
```